# URL from BlobItem

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to get the URL for a `BlobItem`.

In the Azure Portal, I can see the URL in the properties section, but when I get the `BlobItemProperties` object from the `BlobItem`, I cannot find the `URL` property.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

await foreach (var blob in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
{
    blob.Properties.???
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no AbsoluteUri or Uri property available with the latest SDK , what you need to actually do is to generate a url based on the Container Uri.

You can get the Container Uri as,

```
var containerUri = blobContainerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

and then you can generate as

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                results.Add(
                    Flurl.Url.Combine(
                        containerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
                        blobItem.Name
                    )
                );
            }
```

Also make sure to import,

```
using Flurl;
```

Comment: That's with the older SDK. OP is using the newer SDK.

Comment: how did you know OP is using new SDK?

Comment: Use of `BlobContainerClient` class. In the older SDK it is just not there. You gotta research more :).

Comment: I am aware of that, even with the new SDK you have  client.Uri.AbsoluteUri

Comment: OP needs to pass the blob name and get the uri  blobClient.Uri);

Comment: Your answer indicates that there’s a URI property on blob which is just not the case.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS hope it makes sense now

Comment: FWIW, I did downvote it simply because your answer was incorrect initially. I retracted it once I saw the update .

Comment: No i did not mean you! :)

Answer (score 14):

You can do that :

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

await foreach (var blob in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
{
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
    var uri = blobClient.Uri;
}
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer since you could be getting a blob from a specific path (prefix), which you would have to add to your url , and you don't need third party libs.